# imap just inserts instead of executing

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript

I have following mapping

`imap jj :execute 'tabnew'<cfile><CR>`

instead of opening the under the cursor it just puts the string in place.

Comment: imap is an insert mode mapping. you probably want map.

Comment: i especially want this to happen during insert mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the issue out.

`imap` is actually doing exactly as it's told to do. It is going and pressing keys I typed there. So what I was missing to make it press  before the command 
`imap jj <ESC> :tabnew <cfile> <CR>` works perfectly

Comment: @Rich thanks for pointing out I just forgot about this question and I just couldn't immediately accept my own question back then.

Answer (score 4):

You should use  instead of 
So
`imap jj <C-\><C-O> :tabnew <cfile><CR>`

Comment: Welcome to this site! Your answer is flagged as low quality, it would be nice to add an explanation of what `<C-\><C-O>` does and how it differs from the accepted answer: that would be more useful for future users reading your answer.

Comment: [Source](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Ctrl-O_instead_of_Esc_in_insert_mode_mappings) Ctrl-O switches to normal mode for one command, then switches back to insert mode so you can continue typing.